# Any way to block oversize image uploads?

Tags: 2010, rich-text, image-upload

I'm working on a list where anybody in our org will be able to submit content using a rich text area (i.e. column "Multiple lines of text, with images and hyperlinks"). My concern is, and I'm sure you've seen it, is that people will upload pics right from their phone, even if those pics are some crazy 2500 x 3500 pixel size, and then scale 'em down to 250 x 350 px using the drag handles (Ugh!) or the Picture controls in the Ribbon.

I'm wondering if any of y'all have cooked up a way to prevent folks from uploading photos over a particular size; eiter in mb or in pixel width/height. Btw, this is SP2010.

Comment: I think you'd have to do this in an event receiver on itemadding and itemupdating to evaluate the size of the field and cancel if it's too big.

Comment: A swisher method would be a custom HTTP Module to inspect the incoming request, to look for a stream and bail out with an appropriate error code if the stream hits a certain limit. You might also have to manually handle this error code in IIS by redirecting to a custom error page hosted in _layouts.